# Perspective Camera in Car and Maya?

Tags: maya

I'm new to Maya, so is there a way to set the camera to be inside of a car? I understand that there are certain cameras like a perspective camera, but I'm having trouble figuring out if there's a simple way to set a camera, or if it's even possible at all. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a camera **Create -> Cameras -> Camera**, then enable move/rotate tool and put it wherever you want. You can also move even the existing camera to position the same way, or by dragging mouse and *alt+mmb*, *alt+lmb+mmb* and *alt+lmb*.

Comment: I'll try it out, but seems simple enough. Thanks so much for your help!